# How to pass data from parent to child in reactJS after the components have rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I've done a lot of searching and can't seem to find the answer to this - maybe I'm just not using the right terminology.

What I need to do is pass data from a WebSocket component, down to a child component. I'm already passing the WebSocket via props to the child so that it can use the send() function and send data to the socket. I need to also pass any received data via onmessage. Setting this up in the usual way inside the child doesn't work.

What I need to happen is when the data is received in the socket it gets sent to the child, with a function inside the child to then do something with it (send it via MIDI using the Web MIDI API)

Parent

```
class Socket extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ws: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.connect();
  }
  
  connect = () => {
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/");

    ws.onopen = () => {
      this.setState({ ws: ws });    
    };

    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
      const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
      var midi = data["command"]; // Need to send this to the child somehow.
    };

    ......
}

  render() {
    return <MIDIComponent websocket={this.state.ws} />;
  }
}
```

EDIT: So I've managed to get the data from the parent to the child, and I've rendered it to the screen for testing. But I can't extract it inside the functions I need. I've tried combinations of using arrow functions, binding 'this' etc. I either can't access this or the midi ports either come back as undefined or null, the default value.

Child

```
class MIDIComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      midiInput: null,
      midiOutput: null,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const that = this;
    this.setupMIDI(that);
  }

  setupMIDI = (that) => {
    navigator.requestMIDIAccess({ sysex: true }).then(onMIDISuccess);

    function onMIDISuccess(midiAccess) {
      that.setState({ midiInput: Array.from(midiAccess.inputs.values())[0] });
      that.setState({ midiOutput: Array.from(midiAccess.outputs.values())[1] });
      that.state.midiInput.onmidimessage = getMIDIMessage;
// storing the midi ports in the state like this, but it doesnt work.
    }

    function getMIDIMessage(msg) {
      console.log(msg.data);
      that.props.websocket.send(
        JSON.stringify({ message: Array.from(msg.data), type: "config" })
      );
    }
  };

  sendMIDIMessage = (msg) => {
    this.state.midiOutput.send(msg); // need to get to the midiOutput port here to send the data
  };

  render() {
    return <div key={this.props.midi}>{this.props.midi}</div>; // Just using this to render the data to the screen for testing
  }
}
```

I should probably mention that I will be eventually having two Child Components that will need to receive data from the Socket depending on the type of data received. At the moment I'd just like to get it set up using one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dont think you need `that`. What you can do create separate function `getMIDIMessage ` and `sendMIDIMessage ` just like you did for `setupMIDI `. Then every function at same level you either set states for any specific logic or get props for same `this`

Comment: If you update state react will render it again. Just save the data on state.

Comment: OK I will try this thank you, and then I just pass it down via props the same as I am already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply save the received data in the state as well like this:

```
class Socket extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ws: null,
      midi: [] // Create an empty array so that the child always received something and not undefined
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.connect();
  }
  
  connect = () => {
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/");

    ws.onopen = () => {
      this.setState({ ws: ws });    
    };

    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
      const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
      const midi = data["command"]; // Need to send this to the child somehow.
      this.setState({
        midi // Save the received data in the state
      });
    };

}

  render() {
    const {ws, midi} = this.state; // Extract the data from the state
    return <MIDIComponent websocket={ws} midi={midi}/>; // Pass the data as a prop to the child
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yeah I've gotten this far, although slightly differently I can get the data into the child component now and I'm just rendering it inside a <div>. The problem I'm having now is retrieving it inside my child nested functions and getting it to the function I need to use it.

Comment: You can simply use this.props to access the pasted data anywhere within that component.

Comment: I think the problem I'm having is 'this' keeps coming back undefined. I've tried binding it, using arrow functions etc but not working. So I need to use a midiOut port, which is created from the requestMIDIAccess success callback, I've tried saving this in the state and then accessing it from there throughout. I also need the function to send the MIDI data every time the MIDI props updates. I've edited my question to show what I'm doing, if you could take a look? I think a lot of the problem is coming from the MIDI API.

Comment: Ok you do not need to pass this or that in your function. Use arrow functions instead of the function keyword and this works as expected. Since the function keyword does not pass the outer this to the function but instead creates a new reference this (the function itself). So try to remove the function keyword and see if that works for you.

Comment: Yeah I have tried, I think the problem is because getMIDIMessage and onMIDISuccess are callback functions and don't work when I use arrow functions. I will try playing around with it some more. Thanks for your help, as this answers the direct question I asked I accepted your answer. As I think I'm starting to get off topic from the original question I may post a new one if I can't figure it out :)